# Cannot deploy visual webpart from sandboxed Sharepoint 2013 solution

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

I'm trying to deploy a visual webpart to SharePoint 2013 site from sanboxed solution. My webpart RSSNews.ascx (it doesn't have custom code behind):

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RSSNews.ascx.cs" Inherits="Solution.WebParts.RSSNews.RSSNews" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("feeds", "1")
</script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/feeds.js" runat="server" ></script>

<div id="feeds">
</div>
```

When I try to deploy the solution the following errors occur:

**Error 1** Too many characters in character literal    *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 2** Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 3** Method must have a return type  *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 4** } expected  *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 5** Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  *RSSNews.ascx* 
**Error 6** Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 7** A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 8** Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 9** Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 10**    Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 11**    Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 12**    Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 13**    Invalid expression term ')' *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 14**    ) expected  *RSSNews.ascx*
**Error 15**    The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context  *rssnews.ascx.cs*

[Prasath C](http://sharepointserved.blogspot.com/2014/11/too-many-characters-in-character-literal.html)  had the same problem and he says that after he changed Sandboxed Solution to **false** the errors disappeared. But I need a sandboxed solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the cause was the last script reference: it had **runat="server"** attribute. After removing it and adding **type="text/javascript"** everything works fine!